# Is there a way to make a make a superpackage over existing packages in Maven?

Tags: maven

My maven project package structure currently has three packages under src/main/java. They are: ui, domain and dao. However, I'd like to add a new super-package that is one tier above these three. Is there a way to do this in maven without breaking it?

Comment: Watt do you mean with *super package*?

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand the question, but I will try my best.

Package names are usually of the form of an inverse domain. If my domain is `fabianmeier.de`, I would call my packages `de.fabianmeier.someproject.ui`, `de.fabianmeier.someproject.domain` and so on.

These package names correspond to directories in the source and target which are formed by replacing the `.` by a `/` (or in Windows, a `\`). So inside the jar, the resulting classes are in `de/fabianmeier/someproject/ui`.

This has actually little to do with Maven itself, but is a Java convention.